# Calling a getter method without specifiying the object in an if statment

Tags: java

Im practising using getters and setters. Im making a JOption pane that asks users for a hospital patients unique number and returns the patients details. Im naming patient/objects p1, p2, p3 etc. I have created the Getters and Setters in another class file.

My question is, how do I create a single If statement that will accept any of the patient objects as input?

Is there a way I can ask for the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog to call just the getName, getAge etc methods, without me having to create an if statement for every single object/patient? ie p2.getName, p3.getName, p4.getName etc.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person p1 = new Person();
        p1.setpatientNumber(001);
        p1.setName("David");
        p1.setYearOfBirth(1983);
        p1.setFather("Mike");
        p1.setMother("Unknown");

        Person p2 = new Person();
        p2.setpatientNumber(002);
        p2.setName("Simon");
        p2.setYearOfBirth(1979);
        p2.setFather("John");
        p2.setMother("Mary");

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int input = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the patient number"));
        if (p1.getpatientNumber() == input) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Patient details:\n" + p1.getName() + "\n" + p1.getYearOfBirth() + "\n" + p1.getFather() + "\n" + p1.getMother());
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unknown number");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Create a collection of `Person`. Loop.

Comment: The way your question is posed, it sounds like this is from a school class.  The answer is that you need to use a `Collection` or array.  You simply may not have covered this topic yet in your course.  With an assignment like this, I'd guess that lesson should be coming quite soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can add all your `Person` objects to an `ArrayList` and then iterate over them.

```
ArrayList<Person> persons = new ArrayList<Person>;

//Create your persons

persons.add(p1);
persons.add(p2);

//Get input

//Iterate over all persons in the persons ArrayList
for (Person p : persons) {
    if (p.getPatientNumber() == input) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Patient details:\n" + p.getName() + "\n" + p.getYearOfBirth() + "\n" + p.getFather() + "\n" + p.getMother());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your patient in the List or array (if you know the size already), and iterate over the whole list. Something like:

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
personList.add(p1);
personList.add(p2);
```

To search for patient if, do the following:

```
for (Person person : personList) {
    if (person.getpatientNumber() == input) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Patient details:\n" + p1.getName() + "\n" + p1.getYearOfBirth() + "\n" + p1.getFather() + "\n" + p1.getMother());
     }    
 }
```

Note a side: You should use 1/2/3 as patient id and not 001 etc as numbers starting from 0 are treated as octal value in Java.